# Menu endpoint hangs when access callback returns false

Tags: 7

I'm trying to add a custom access callback function that checks that a user is a specific user (we only want this one api user to have this specific endpoint. It is set up like so:

```
function my_module_menu() {
    return array(
        '/api/v1/sample/request' => array(
            'page callback' => 'sample_request',
            'access callback' => 'user_is_api_user',
            'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        )
    );
}

function user_is_api_user() {
    watchdog("GLOBALS", "<pre>" . print_r($GLOBALS['user'], true) . "</pre>");
    return $GLOBALS['user']->name == 'api';
}
```

If my custom `user_is_api_user` function returns FALSE, the endpoint just hangs instead of sending back a 403 Forbidden (like expected). Instead, it looks it just keeps retrying because my recent logs just repeat the error `not authorized` and the watchdog log I put in over and over again until I end the request.

If my custom `user_is_api_user` returns TRUE, it logs the user in fine. Why does it just look and not actually return 403 forbidden when my custom function return false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return `403 Forbidden` in your callback function, use [drupal_access_denied()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_access_denied/7.x) function something like:

```
function user_is_api_user() {
  watchdog("GLOBALS", "<pre>" . print_r($GLOBALS['user'], TRUE) . "</pre>");
  if ($GLOBALS['user']->name !== 'api'){
    drupal_access_denied();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. Just curious, if I have to invoke `drupal_access_denied()` method, how come `user_is_logged_in` does not but it works there?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by **how come user_is_logged_in does not but it works there?**

Comment: The user.module provides the method `user_is_logged_in` that is used as the access callback all around drupal. But all user logged in does is this one line: `return (bool) $GLOBALS['user']->uid;`. It never calls `drupal_access_denied()`, yet an endpoint that uses that function as the access callback returns 403 Forbidden when this function returns false. Why does that function just return a boolean, but my function has to call this drupal_access_denied method? Those are inconsistent patterns

Comment: Yes you are right, i just about to test, the `'access callback'` function should return a boolean, i miss placed the use of the function, the best way is to use `drupal_access_denied()` with the condition in your `'page callback'` in this case `sample_request` function and let `user_is_api_user` as it is

Comment: So just don't use the access callback for what it's for? lol, classic drupal BS

Comment: Actually your code should work, i have tested it it return 403 page, i just suggested another way to do it, the `'access callback'` should work, and it works i copied your code, besides you have some errors in your code `=> {` should be `=> array(`

Comment: take a look https://gist.github.com/BERRAMOU/813633c7af9e4a4789f728e94d2ebb4e

Comment: Yeah the typo was just for this answer. I fixed it to what it is in my actual codebase.

Comment: Did you the example I post in the comment Bellow is that result you want ?